# PHP foreach inside Array

Tags: php

I try to use foreach inside an array but I get error

my php code is :

```
<?php
      $items = [
            foreach ($model->galleries as $glrThm){

            [
                'url' => Url::home().$glrThm->Gallery_image,
                'src' => Url::home().$glrThm->Gallery_imagethumb,
            ],

        }   
    ];
?>
```

Comment: That's because you can't do that. Why are you doing it this way? PHP makes adding items to an array *easy*.

Comment: Yes, invalid syntax would be expected to produce an error.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  If you just want to push items onto an array, then first create an empty array and then loop through your items and push them onto the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that construct/syntax is not allowed.

If you would like to use something like it then [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) could be for you:

```
$items = array_map( function( $glrThm ){
    return [
        'url' => Url::home().$glrThm->Gallery_image,
        'src' => Url::home().$glrThm->Gallery_imagethumb
    ];
}, $model->galleries );
```

---

If you need or wish to use `foreach()` then this is the proper syntax:

```
$items = [];

foreach ($model->galleries as $glrThm){
    $items[] = [
        'url' => Url::home().$glrThm->Gallery_image,
        'src' => Url::home().$glrThm->Gallery_imagethumb
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, honestly Thank you so much for your solution

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is not allowed.

First create your array

```
<?php
$items = [];
```

Then loop over your other array picking the items you want to transfer

```
foreach ($model->galleries as $glrThm){

    $items[] = ['url' => $glrThm->Gallery_image,
                'src' => $glrThm->Gallery_imagethumb,
               ];

}   
?>
```